# Is it possible to get_attribute() from several elements with the same name?

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have a lot of list elements with the same class name but with different id.

Example:

```
<li class="test class" id="111-11-111"> pass </li>
<li class="test class" id="222-22-222"> pass </li>
<li class="test class" id="333-33-333"> pass </li>
```

And I need to extract those id's.
For a single list element it is not a problem:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".test.class").get_attribute("id")
```

But I need to somehow reach to a next id's.
If try to `find_elements_by...` I receive the following exception:

> 'list' object has no attribute `'get_attribute'`.

Is there a way to extract them?

Comment: Yes, loop over the list  find_elements_by returns and pull the id from each exactly as you did when you used find_element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use xpath:

```
listOfLi = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[class='test class']")
```

or css selector:

```
listOfLi = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".test.class")
```

you can access each li element by indexing them one by one:

```
for eachLiElement in listOfLi:
    string = eachLiElement.get_attribute("id")
```

`string` will give you each element's id.

If you only want to get the second id, you can do it by

`secondId = listOfLi[1].get_attribute("id")`

`secondId` will have `222-22-222`

Answer (score 0):

Using `get_attribute()` to extract the value of the *id* attributes of all the `<li>` tags you can use the following solution:

```
print([my_element.get_attribute("id") for my_element in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.test.class')])
```